# fancybox-like inline popup implementation problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm busy writing my very first jquery plugin and i ran into some problems. I have modified and customized other people's plugins quite succesfully in the past, but i'm more a designer than a programmer and this is my first javascript/jquery experiment build from scratch.
 with a lot of research and plenty of try and error i managed to realize most of the features i wanted.
 and besides the code probably being dirty, inconsistent and a pita for every pro, the plugin is working pretty well.
 the problem i have is, the way i've written it, i apparently cannot use more than one intance of the plugin on one page. if i do, it breaks appart. i tried to wrap the whole thing into a this.each function, but this as well breaks everything appart. right now, i have no clue at all, how to make this work.
 I'm grateful for any suggestions or hints, as my brain slowly starts to boil.
here's the little sucker: [the .js file](http://www.counterculture-design.com/culturebox.js) 
you can see it in action here: [demo](http://www.counterculture-design.com/demo_js_test.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say more then one instance, I'm imagining a clone of your demo, so two of the same thing on one page.

one problem I see is that you are using ID's in your plugin, and you shouldn't be using ID's when you want multiples of the same thing to be able to live on the same page. try and switch to classes.

Comment: yep, thats exactly what i'm trying to achieve. thanks for the quick reply. i will try switching to classes instead. i had a problem with the .append method not working with class but only with id, thats why i went with id's in the first place. but maybe i just made some mistake.

Comment: i also have the strong sense that my code in't exactly straight foreward and it gets more and more difficult to extend it with new features. any piece of advice on how to put more logic into the whole thing is more than welcome. 
thanks!

Comment: sure...while I don't have a ton of experience with plugins themselves, I might be able to offer some advice on extensibility in general. wherever you can, put code into functions. so for example, anything that needs to be initialized before any actions are taken, put into an init() function. you want to make your code modular, so ideally if you want to add any new feature to your plugin you shouldnt have to change ANY of your previous code. this is hard, but worthwhile in the end. check out this documentation if you haven't yet http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: i read the tutorial, but probably too late. i'd just started playing around a little, to see if i can put some simple jquery stuff together myself. when i actually read the tutorial, i already had written so much, it was hard to reorganize it. i tried to wrap some parts into functions, but whenever i did, i failed to succesfully call them. i still have to figure out what i'm doing wrong there. anyway, i'll keep trying! thanks again for your realy quick and helpful answer

Comment: hi everyone, hi evan, i pretty much cleaned up everything and i can even call multiple instances of the plugin on one page. my problem now is, that a lot of the options which override the defaults are applied to all the plugin instances, instead of the individual settings applied to the corresponding plugin instance. i figuered that all the option-values used inside the click-function properly change according to what is set in the options of the individual plugin call.

Comment: however, all the rest, that is used outside the click-function only takes the values of the last plugin-call on the page. so basically, if i move everything that uses options inside the click-function, everything should be fine. but that doesn't seem to be a rather elegant way. is there anything else i could do, to get around this issue? cheers, boris